# What is the correct way to refresh the UI after changing a ListView in Terminal.GUI (gui.cs)?

Tags: c#, terminal.gui

I am using [gui.cs](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs).

I have a [ListView](https://migueldeicaza.github.io/gui.cs/api/Terminal.Gui/Terminal.Gui.ListView.html) that shows network nodes. These nodes come and go so the list gets updated on the right events.

```
var clients = new List<Node>();
var clientList = new ListView(clients)
{
    Height = Dim.Fill(),
    Width = Dim.Fill(),
};

server.NodeJoined += (s, e) =>
{
    clients.Add(e.Node);
    Application.Refresh();
};

server.NodeLeft += (s, e) =>
{
    var client = clients.FirstOrDefault(n => n.IP == e.Node.IP);
    if (client != null) clients.Remove(client);
    Application.Refresh();
};
```

Currently I'm using the [`Application.Refresh()`](https://migueldeicaza.github.io/gui.cs/api/Terminal.Gui/Terminal.Gui.Application.html#Terminal_Gui_Application_Refresh) which updates the whole UI. Ideally only the changed parts should be updated. Is this correct or is there a better way to inform `ListView` that the data source has changed and it needs a redraw?

Comment: *Ideally only the changed parts should be updated* => This notion becomes buggy as simple UI becomes complex with inter-related data, like,  the real world. A thick web of event handling plus many (it's only simple ones!) data field rules in the UI - and thus left out of the business model, are root causes.

Comment: Looking at the [API Reference](https://migueldeicaza.github.io/gui.cs/api/Terminal.Gui/Terminal.Gui.html) for that project, I see a [`Redraw`](https://migueldeicaza.github.io/gui.cs/api/Terminal.Gui/Terminal.Gui.View.html#Terminal_Gui_View_Redraw_Terminal_Gui_Rect_) function that says to always use  the [`Bounds`](https://migueldeicaza.github.io/gui.cs/api/Terminal.Gui/Terminal.Gui.View.html#Terminal_Gui_View_Bounds) property. Dunno if that will work, never used that project before, but it seems promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to make UI changes from a callback is to use [MainLoop.Invoke](https://migueldeicaza.github.io/gui.cs/api/Terminal.Gui/Terminal.Gui.MainLoop.html#Terminal_Gui_MainLoop_Invoke_System_Action_).  If you do that then you can simply call [SetNeedsDisplay](https://migueldeicaza.github.io/gui.cs/api/Terminal.Gui/Terminal.Gui.View.html#Terminal_Gui_View_SetNeedsDisplay) on your View.

The Invoke ensures that list content changes don't occur while the view is rendering and means that SetNeedsDisplay is immediately detected and the redraw occurs.

```
ListView clientList = new ListView();
Application.MainLoop.Invoke(()=>
{
    // TODO: Change list contents here

    // Tell view to redraw
    clientList.SetNeedsDisplay();
});
```